# Distributed transaction in Oracle among requests

Tags: oracle, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

I have the following scenario:

1. User opens a form to edit an entity and its child entities.
2. User submits the form.
3. Client (front-end) sends multiple requests to persist the changes in database (one for parent entity and one for each child).

If the first requests succeds but the last one fails, i need to rollback all of them.

Considerations:

- The database is centralized and the system is distributed. So every request will persist in the same database, but not every request will be handled by the same node.
- I cannot change this architecture, so i really need to be able to start a transaction and use this one transaction among multiple database connections and at the end of them all, commit or rollback the transaction.

Does oracle supports this feature? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You have multiple connections to the same Oracle RAC database and you want them all to commit in a single distributed transaction? There may be a way but I am not sure. If you had one connection and updated multiple databases via database links it would all be one transaction.

Comment: You may try to implement it with [Oracle XA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_xa.htm#ADFNS1503) and specifically with [DBMS_XA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xa.htm#ARPLS209) package. But it may require to rewrite your backend code to use PL/SQL wrappers or do preliminary calls to this interface. Another option may be external broker who coordinates success/error of each request and tells individual workers to commit/rollback

Comment: Typically this would be handled by the front-end making a _single_ call to a database stored procedure/back-end API, which would process everything as a single transaction in a PL/SQL block and return a success or failure message to the client. Seems like you're going to have to rewrite something, and I would suggest that this approach would be much simpler and more scalable than trying to build a convoluted multi-session transaction paradigm from scratch.